# cortex m1 hard fault at ldrsh

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-m

Hello everyone i have HardFault exception on my cortex m1 many times at the same place. I've got HardFault implementation and i can read stacked registers:

stacked_r0  unsigned int    0x4 (Hex)
stacked_r1  unsigned int    0x60905f98 (Hex)
stacked_r2  unsigned int    0x0 (Hex)
stacked_r3  unsigned int    0x6092304b (Hex)
stacked_r12 unsigned int    0x60922ff8 (Hex)
stacked_lr  unsigned int    0x60810be3 (Hex)
stacked_pc  unsigned int    0x60810ce2 (Hex)
stacked_psr unsigned int    0x41000000 (Hex)

the operation at stacked PC is:
60810ce2:   ldrsh   r2, [r3, r2]

why it causes fault?

upd
i've rearranged variables and for now it has crashed in memcpy called from freertos code

stacked_r0  unsigned int    0x6090c858 (Hex)
stacked_r1  unsigned int    0x6091f8b4 (Hex)
stacked_r2  unsigned int    0x3c (Hex)
stacked_r3  unsigned int    0x6091f8a4 (Hex)
stacked_r12 unsigned int    0x280 (Hex) 
stacked_lr  unsigned int    0x60827f89 (Hex)
stacked_pc  unsigned int    0x6082b0dc (Hex)
stacked_psr unsigned int    0x1000000 (Hex)

6082b0ba:   bne.n   0x6082b120

6082b0bc:   adds    r5, r2, #0

6082b0be:   adds    r4, r0, #0

6082b0c0:   subs    r5, #16

6082b0c2:   lsrs    r5, r5, #4

6082b0c4:   adds    r5, #1

6082b0c6:   lsls    r5, r5, #4

6082b0c8:   adds    r1, r1, r5

6082b0ca:   ldr     r6, [r3, #0]

6082b0cc:   str     r6, [r4, #0]

6082b0ce:   ldr     r6, [r3, #4]

6082b0d0:   str     r6, [r4, #4]

6082b0d2:   ldr     r6, [r3, #8]

6082b0d4:   str     r6, [r4, #8]

6082b0d6:   ldr     r6, [r3, #12]

6082b0d8:   adds    r3, #16

6082b0da:   str     r6, [r4, #12]

6082b0dc:   adds    r4, #16

Comment: that is an unaligned access.

Comment: okay, but why? r3 points at stack

Comment: stack is ram, what does stack have to do with it the lower bits are 0xB or 1011 for ldrsh or ldrh the lower bit has to be a zero for ldr, the lower two have to be zeros for ldrd the lower three have to be zeros.   you are trying to do an unaligned halfword access and the processor properly stopped you from doing it.

Comment: right. i'm using freertos and GCC. It's looks like it's generates code which is not manipulating stack addresses by 8 bytes or not?

Comment: If you want to get into what the compiler is doing you have to provide a simple example function, the compiler and options, and output and go from there.  not sure why gcc would be using r3 nor r2 to access the stack, a load has nothing to do with alignment of the stack anyway.

Comment: you can access the stack however you want that has nothing to do with stack alignment, this particular instruction tried to do a 16 bit read on an address that is not 16 bit aligned (the lsbit was set), it is as simple as that, if the compiler produced it then it is most likely what you told the compiler to do with your code or options.

Comment: from the arm docs Alignment support
ARMv6-M only supports naturally aligned memory accesses for 16-bit halfword and 32-bit word accesses
using the LDR , LDRH , LDRSH , STR and STRH instructions. ARMv7-M supports unaligned accesses from these
instructions.

Comment: you are using a cortex-m1 right?  and that is armv6m I think, even if armv7m you would likely need to disable the unaligned access trap.

Comment: i'm running gcc with followed options arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m1 -march=armv6-m -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mno-unaligned-access -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

Comment: still need to see your code at least the code related to this access.  it is not just compiler options that affect these things.

Comment: looks like that it happens there
 for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
 {
  qr_buff[0][i]   =   qr[i];
 }
qr_buff and qr are static double and i is int16_t

Comment: So it is reading i from the stack because of the lack of optimization.  So long as you didnt do anything funny (packed structures, inline code, etc) in or around this function then the compiler should be simply reading that i value and writing it back every loop.  Still not enough information, what are you using to get the register values?  why not single step into this function and look at the stack pointer on entry and what happens as it eventually gets placed in r3 as is or with an offset.

Comment: also try optimizing and/or try rearranging the local variables in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of compiler generating alignment using ldrsh:

```
short more_fun ( short );
short fun ( short a )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    short x[16];
    for(ra=0;ra<16;ra++)
    {
        a+=more_fun(x[ra]);
    }
    return(a);
}
```

arm-none-eabi-gcc -mthumb -O2 -c so.c -o so.o -march=armv6-m
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   2:   b088        sub sp, #32
   4:   0004        movs    r4, r0
   6:   466d        mov r5, sp
   8:   ae08        add r6, sp, #32
   a:   2300        movs    r3, #0
   c:   5ee8        ldrsh   r0, [r5, r3]
   e:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <more_fun>
  12:   3502        adds    r5, #2
  14:   1904        adds    r4, r0, r4
  16:   b224        sxth    r4, r4
  18:   42b5        cmp r5, r6
  1a:   d1f6        bne.n   a <fun+0xa>
  1c:   0020        movs    r0, r4
  1e:   b008        add sp, #32
  20:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
  22:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

the stack is remaining aligned, the stack manipulation, pushing, popping and stack frame are all multiples of 8 bytes (two words).

The array is on the stack and they use r5 basically as the index into the array, looks like ldrsh requires two registers so they set r3 to zero so they can have a second register.  And the key here is they start off aligned, the sp address has at least the lower three bits zeros assuming everyone outside this code has conformed to the convention.  Then the code adds 2 to r5 each time through the loop, keeping the pointer to the array aligned on a halfword boundary, lower bit remains zero for the address for every use of ldrsh.  No alignment issues.

Please provide a similar exmaple, maybe fragments of code, but certainly the relevant fragments around the unaligned ldrsh.